# changing the status value to 1 when the diff is <0 in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying to update the Status column in my data set when the Diff value is < 0, so therefore when the Diff value is a -neg number I want to make the Status column = 1 to represent a change.
below is sample code of my data set which is all numeric:

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(diff=c("4","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","-30","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "14","0","0","0","0","0","0","-55","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","-40","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","-30","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0"),
             status=c("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created a difficult problem by giving a set of character values to the data.frame function. By default that will create factor variables unless you set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Two thing are consequential: the comparisons to 0 will fail and assignment to a value that doesn't exist in the df$status column will likewise fail.

```
df <- data.frame(diff=c("4","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","-30","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "14","0","0","0","0","0","0","-55","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","-40","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","-30","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0"),
             status=c("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                      "0","0","0","0","0"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Once those issues are put aside you can get success with a logical indexed assignment like:

```
df$status[as.numeric(df$diff) < 0 ] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- df %>%
      mutate(status = ifelse(diff < 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: can you explain the code how this will solve the problem?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks Joseph, this works a dream, one thing I have to remove the NA's values first so that I don't get any errors

Comment: I don't think the code actually works. Would have expected the factor nature of the diff column to cause problems with a numeric comparison... and it did.